# Login fails on first attempt, after it works properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Right now i am working on localhost for testing of my project.. but when try to login for the first time. it shows nothing means page don't redirect('admin/dashboard');.. 
But when i try next time.. it works everything fine.. 
Please anyone can help!!
Thanks in advance.

[I am adding a image here. so that you can see what actual the problem was,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEH87.png)

This is model file.

```
<?php 

class Admin_model extends CI_Model{
    public function login($username,$password){
        $enc = md5($password); //for password encryption
        $this->db->where('username',$username);
        $this->db->where('password',$enc);
        $result=$this->db->get('admin');
        if($result->num_rows()==1){
            return $result->row();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my controller file.

```
<?php

class Admin_login extends CI_Controller{

    public function __Construct(){
        parent::__Construct();
        $this->load->model('admin_model','secure_admin_model');  //here i am including model file..  
    }
    public function login(){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required');
        if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
            $this->load->view('admin/layouts/admin_login');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
        }
        else{
            $username=$this->input->post('username');
            $password=$this->input->post('password'); // i am using md5 for hashing
            $userid=$this->secure_admin_model->login($username,$password);
            if($userid){
                $user_data=array(
                    'user_id'=>$userid,
                    'username'=>$username,
                    'logged_in'=>true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($user_data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('pass_login','You are logged in'); // Here i am creating session..
                redirect('admin/dashboard');
            }
            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('wrong_pass','Wrong Username and password'); // for wrong password
                redirect('admin/login');
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side note: I hope that this is for education purposes, seeing that you're using MD5 to store passwords with. Or... is this for a live site? If it is, stop what you're doing and use `password_hash()` for this. You'll probably thank me for it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I doubt it :)

Comment: _General Point_ Dont use the password in the query! Query the user, then compare the retrieved password with the entered password

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner No this is not live site.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried.. But same issue.

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error message either on screen or on your logs?

Comment: @JavierLarroulet No.. loading goes on.

Comment: You are returning either a row or false and then checking the result to see if it's true. Try changing it to return the row or null and use isset on the result

Comment: @MarkS. Still the same issue.. i tried isset and !empty both..

Comment: Have you tried moving the unset_userdata after the load_view? Generally, load_view should be the last call.

Comment: following what @MarkS. suggested regarding the model returning a row or false, in your controller try changing the `if` clause to specifically `if($userid !== false)`

Comment: @JavierLarroulet No mam still the same issue..

Comment: I have added an image. so that you can visualize the actual problem.